# Cannot add inline image/picture to a Rich Text control

Tags: ckeditor, xpages, rich-text-editor

I have a Rich Text control bound to a Body field in my Domino Document data source ... all is good for ***formatting text*** , :) emoticons and the usual stuff.  The problem is when I try to paste or upload an inline image I get the following error shown in the inline image (hmmmm, works here) ...

[image]

Comment: I may be wrong about this, but I don't think CKEditor allows for uploads from the local file system. I think you have to add it as a resource and refer to it using the full URL in order to add to the body. I could be wrong about this though. Edit: I'm looking at this and it does say "from your computer", so I may be in error, but if the alternative works it may still be a good work around.

Comment: You did click on 1a) choose file 1b) Upload Image and 2) OK? Without 1b you get that error

Comment: Thanks Stephan that worked ... perfect, I get to tell the client its a user error ... gotta admit though, not obvious, not high on the usability scale

Comment: The error message should state: "Please click on Upload image". HTML File upload can't be automatic, since it would open the floodgates of automatically stealing files from known locations. (Feel free to accept the answer below)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely a mis-understanding of the steps:

1. Select the file
2. Click on upload image (<-- that one gets lost on lots of users)
3. Click OK

For a more advanced user experience:
Use the [RichText Editor Evolution](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20Rich%20Text%20Editor%20Evolution) from OpenNTF. That makes your life much easier.